# Memory corruption with suspected strftime on 64-bit Linux system

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, strftime

I have C++ codebase that gets built on Solaris 10 using `g++` toolchain v4.9.2. This codebase is being ported to Linux 64-bit. I am facing a strange runtime core dump caused by `SIGSEGV` while doing apparently innocent call `strftime`. The API `strftime` has the following signature:

```
size_t strftime(char *s, size_t max, const char *format,
                       const struct tm *tm);
```

As we all know `size_t` is `64-bit (unsigned long)` on a 64-bit executable whereas it was 32-bit on a 32-bit system.
I have some function as below:

```
void somefunc(X *& p)
{
  p = new X[20000];
  // p gets allocated and have a decent pointer value
  char s[30];
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tmp = localtime(&t);
  strftime(s, 30, "%Y %m %d %T", tmp); // apparently innocent call
  // after this, p gets garbled and access to p cause crash  
}
```

Same code on 32-bit Solaris system runs perfectly ok, but causing runtime memory corruption on Linux-64-bit.
Just a suspect, could size of size_t being 8-byte vs 4-byte could be an issue? For example, just to drawn an analogy, while doing simple `printf`, 32-bit `size_t` would require `%d` as format specifier whereas 64-bit `size_t` would require `%ld` as format specifier. Could similar kind of reason exist for strftime formatting as well?
Another clue, if I comment out strftime statement, the code runs ok on 64-bit.
Sounds peculiar and surprising. Thoughts, please.

Comment: Are you sure a 30 character buffer is big enough?  What is the return value from `strftime`?

Comment: Another thing: `size_t` does not have to be `unsigned long`, it can be `unsigned long long` or any other type that satisfy the requirement of being able to represent any objects size.

Comment: I don't really get your sentence about `%d` and size_t size because in this format string `%d` stands for day of the month (this is not `printf`). The first suspicious thing here is use non-reentrant version of `localtime`. If this is multithreaded application the value of `*tmp` may change randomly.

Comment: This call ensures mutual exclusion, and regarding size_t, I just mentioned %d to bring analogy with printf treating for formatting, I was guessing strftime must be using some similar mechanism

Comment: @NathanOliver from documentation http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html, I think 30 is not too small, do you see any more suspect causing the memory corruption other than strftime? Commenting out strftime takes the corruption away

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana What does `strftime` return when you call it?

Comment: @NathanOliver it's 19, and commenting the strftime statement does not produce anymemory corruption, strange!

Comment: I have no evidence to confirm this, but it sounds like a bug in the `strftime` where the timestamp fails to get null-terminated.  If this theory is correct, you can work around it by zeroing `s` prior to the call to `strftime`:  `char s[30] = {0};`.

Comment: `X *& p` looks iffy to me.  What pointer is it a reference to?